# Swift Realm: creating instance of Realm throws NSException

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
OSX 10.11,  Swift 2.2, Realm 0.99
```

I have installed Realm using Carthage.

**`let realm = try! Realm()`**  throws an `NSException`:

`libc++abi.dylib`: terminating with uncaught exception of type `NSException`

The project compiles, builds and runs until the Realm instantiation.
Both Realm frameworks files are in the project's embedded binaries and embedded frameworks.
and they are in the Carthage/Build/IOS folder.
They also appear in the link binary with libraries section of build phases.

Help is very appreciated.

Realm installation:

```
Install Carthage 0.9.2 or later.
Add github "realm/realm-cocoa" to your Cartfile.
Run carthage update.

Drag RealmSwift.framework and Realm.framework from the appropriate platform directory in Carthage/Build/ to the “Embedded Binaries” section of your Xcode project’s “General” settings.

iOS/watchOS/tvOS: On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”. 
Create a Run Script with the following contents:

/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks

and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:

$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Realm.framework

$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework*
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, the problem was a non-optional declaration in a class.
At a loss why that couldn't be caught. Total waste of time.